# What regression problem this closed-form solution solves (if any)?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, loss-functions

In my company, I stumbled upon a piece of software whose purpose is to correct with fresher data some future forecasts made by a complex system.

To formalize a little bit: there's a forecasting model $x \mapsto f(x)$ which is trained on a dataset $\mathcal D$ to forecast an underlying process $y$. There exists a fresher dataset $\mathcal D_{new}$ whose information are only partial and cannot be used directly to train $f$ (for technical and theoretical reasons).
What they do is correcting predictions of $f$ by a multiplicative factor $\beta$.

This factor is computed by the following formula:
$$ \beta=\frac{\sum_{(x,y)\in\mathcal D_{new}} y}{\sum_{(x,y)\in\mathcal D_{new}} f(x)} \qquad \qquad(1)$$
This is working quite well in practice.

However, I noticed that this not the optimal least squares solution. When solving the ordinary linear regression $y \approx \beta_{LR} f(x)$ (*$f$ being fixed, of course*), the solution is
$$ \beta_{LR}=\frac{\sum_{(x,y)\in\mathcal D_{new}} yf(x)}{\sum_{(x,y)\in\mathcal D_{new}} f(x)^2} $$

**My question:** what problem the equation (1) is the solution to?

**EDIT:**
A linear regression  $E[y|z] = \beta z + \varepsilon$ (where $z=f(x)$) with another loss? Another type of regression? (I couldn't find any problem with such closed-form solution...)

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple. Let me change the notation a bit, let's say that

$$\mathcal{D}_{new} = \Big\{(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), \dots, (x_n, y_n)\Big\}$$

so it has size $|\mathcal{D}_{new}| = n$. Now, we can write

$$
\beta = \frac{\tfrac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n y_i}{\tfrac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)}
$$

The average $y_i$ is $\beta$ times higher (or lower) than the average $f(x_i)$. To correct the predictions (on average) you just multiply it by $\beta$. This works by the linearity of expectation $E[cX] = c E[X]$. Since $\tfrac{1}{n}$s cancel out, we don't need them in the formula and can work with the sums rather than the averages. If you care about the totals, the interpretation makes sense also in terms of the totals.

This assumes that there is a multiplicative difference between the observed values and the predictions $E[y] = \beta E[f(x)]$. If there would be an additive difference (the predictions on average would be off by a constant $\alpha$), you could calculate $\alpha = E[y] - E[f(x)]$ and correct it $E[y] = E[f(x)] + \alpha$.

Notice that it *does not* aim to correct the individual predictions, just their average. It assumes that the function $f$ is correct, but off by a multiplicative constant. $\bar y \big/ \bar x$ wouldn't work for estimating the regression coefficient as in a linear regression model. In this sense, this is not really a regression model. $E[y|x] = \beta x + \varepsilon$ would be a regression model, while you have $E[y] = \beta E[x]$.

Comment: @Pop the procedure does not aim at fitting the optimal regression line. It already assumes that the regression line $f(x)$ is optimal, but off by a constant. If you want to fit the optimal regression model, just use the new data to fit it directly.

Comment: Indeed, it is a multiplicative coefficient, but it is not the optimal one for Mean Square Error, because the optimal one is the solution of the linear regression model  $E[y|f(x)] = \beta f(x) + \varepsilon$.

My question purpose was to know what loss it is optimal for in this above linear regression setting (where $f(x)$ is used to predict $y$)

Comment: (Sorry I deleted by error my previous comment)

Comment: But, do you agree that this new constant finding problem can be written as a new regression problem? Not between x and y, but between $z=f(x)$ and y. And if you solve it, you do not get the $\bar y / \bar z$ solution, but $\bar{zy} / \bar{z^2}$

Comment: @Pop no it is not a regression problem. Its pure arithmetics. It does not assume any noise distribution.